# Find x and y full width half maximums of 2D peak using interpolation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, interpolation, spline

Given a 2D numpy array of data, I've written code that computes the FWHM in the x and y directions. However, my method is pretty simple and only returns integer values for these widths. If possible, I'd like to implement some sort of interpolation so that I can get precise floating point values for the widths. I've seen some examples using scipy spline interpolation in 1D, but I am unsure how to extend that to 2D in my case. I'm also still a bit confused on how spline works in general. Below is the code I have with a simple example of data (though my real data is much larger).

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 2, 5, 91, 27], [5, 41, 80, 66, 52], [56, 101, 122, 115, 9], [21, 55, 81, 5, 7], [90, 22, 37, 24, 2]])
amp = np.max(data)
ypix, xpix = np.where(data==amp)
x_range = np.take(data, ypix[0], axis=0)
print(x_range)
>>> [ 56 101 122 115   9]
y_range = np.take(data, xpix[0], axis=1)
print(y_range)
>>> [  5  80 122  81  37]

half_max = amp/2.0
d_x = x_range - half_max
d_y = y_range - half_max
indices_x = np.where(d_x>0)[0]
indices_y = np.where(d_y>0)[0]

# FMHM in x and y - simply counts how many pixels are within half the max in both directions
width_x = len(indices_x)
width_y = len(indices_y)
```

How can I add in an interpolation method to make these widths more precise? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would try to fit a 2D-Gaussain over the array... but It looks like you already try this in another question, why it didn't work?  Otherwise, try to apply the 1D fit method over the slices going through the position of the maximum: `data[ypix, :]` and `data[:, xpix]`

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on this method now and it seems a lot more accurate than my previously attempted fit to the 2D array! The only thing is some of the predicted standard deviations seem abnormally high